# Unable to inject IEnumerable<T> in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have an interface called IConfiTab which will be implemented in various spots of my code.

I want code to be able to do this...

```
// Add all IConfig instances as user controls to the settings tabs if they are 
// configured to do so
foreach (var configTab in _configTabs)
{
    if (configTab.ShowTab)
    {
        //add Config Tab instance to GUI here
    }
}
```

_configTabs should be some sort of Collection of instances of each type of IConfigTab found.

I used the following code to try to register all found types of IConfigTab.

```
// Register all IConfigTabs we find in the current runtime 
var iconfigTypes = 
    from nd in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in nd.GetExportedTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where typeof(IConfigTab).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select type;

foreach (var iconfigType in iconfigTypes)
{
    container.Register(iconfigType);
}

container.Verify();

var configTabs = container.GetInstance<IEnumerable<IConfigTab>>().ToArray();
```

The problem is configTabs has a size of 0.

Is this possible to do?  I want Simple Injector to return an instance of each class of type `IConfigTab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer.

```
// Simple Injector v3.x syntax
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IConfigTab),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Simple Injector v2.x syntax
// Register all IConfigTabs we find in the current runtime 
var iconfigTypes =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where typeof(IConfigTab).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select type;

container.RegisterAll(typeof(IConfigTab), iconfigTypes);
```

You have to use `RegisterCollection` and specify what the service type is (in this case `IConfigTab`) as well as pass it a list of implementation types.